# How to interact with objects in front of a character in unity using rays?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So as far as I understand I should use a Raycast, I'm confused as to how to use the syntax however. I have a square that's my character, in his script I have wasd movement, and am storing the last used direction as an enum.
I want to shoot a ray for x distance if I press f to check for an interactable object in that distance.

Heres my current player script.

```
    using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class WorldInteraction : MonoBehaviour {
    Camera cam;
    public int movementspeed = 3;
    public enum LastDirection
    {
        none,
        forward,
        left,
        back,
        right
    };
    public LastDirection lastdirection;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        cam = Camera.main;
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
//todo: switch to dpad and a button
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
        {
            transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * movementspeed * Time.deltaTime);
            lastdirection = LastDirection.forward;
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        {
            transform.Translate(Vector3.left * movementspeed * Time.deltaTime);
            lastdirection = LastDirection.left;
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.R))
        {
            transform.Translate(Vector3.back * movementspeed * Time.deltaTime);
            lastdirection = LastDirection.back;
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
        {
            transform.Translate(Vector3.right * movementspeed * Time.deltaTime);
            lastdirection = LastDirection.right;
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.F))
        {
            //interact with object in last direction

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you rotate your square and use his "forward" vector ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to set up something to translate the last used direction as a useful vector. for instance:

```
Vector3 vectordir;
if (LastDirection == lastdirection.right)
    vectordir = Vector3.right;
```

Then cast a ray in that direction when F is pressed.

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.F))
{
    RaycastHit hit;

    if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, vectordir, out hit))
        //do something here
}
```